# Center align text in td next to the image

Tags: html, css

This is how the text looks at the moment

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<td style="vertical-align:middle;">
   <img src="~/Images/Cancel.png" style="width:80px;height:80px" id="btnCancel" />
   <span style="color:White;font-size:27px;font-weight:bold;">CANCEL</span>
</td>
```

How can I vertically align the text next to the image so it's in the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the `vertical-align:middle;` from the table cell and apply that CSS declaration to both `<img>` and the `span>` element, as follows:

```
<td>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100" style="width:80px;height:80px;vertical-align:middle;" id="btnCancel" />
    <span style="color:black;font-size:27px;font-weight:bold;vertical-align:middle;">CANCEL</span>
</td>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/negun/1/edit)**.

That's because the inline elements themselves are aligned in their **baseline** by default.

Comment: Thank you, this is the simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

Try giving `float:left` in css:

```
<img src="~/Images/Cancel.png" style="width:80px;height:80px; float:left" id="btnCancel" />
<span style="color:White;font-size:27px;font-weight:bold; float:left margin:5px 0 0 5px;">CANCEL</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make both the image and span display:inline-block you will be able to user vertical-align: middle.

```
<td style="vertical-align:middle;">
   <img style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle; width:80px; height:80px" src="~/Images/Cancel.png" id="btnCancel" />
   <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle; color: White; font-size: 27px; font-weight: bold;">CANCEL</span>
</td>
```

Comment: `vertical-align` property is applicable to inline elements as well. there's no need to change the default display type of the elements to `inline-block` in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="vertical-align:middle;">
   <img src="~/Images/Cancel.png" style="width:80px;height:80px;float:left" id="btnCancel" />
   <span style="color:White;font-size:27px;font-weight:bold;float:left; padding:24px 0 0 0">CANCEL</span>
</td>
```